# Atom autocomplete plus navigation, not working

Tags: autocomplete, navigation, toggle, atom-editor

For as long as i can remember, the navigation on my autocomplete menu haven't work, it pop's up, and i'm able to select the first suggestion,

But on arrow-up, or down, nothing seems to happen,

[image: Atom Navigation]

I've tried toggling the issue and so on, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by editing the keymap.cson file in atom with some custom navigation.

```
body atom-text-editor.autocomplete-active':
  'tab': 'autocomplete-plus:move-down'
```

An then i set `'enter'` as the select key in the Autocomplete plus package settings